# flutter error when creating more than one table in the same line of code

Tags: flutter

when I create my database it doesn't recognize the groups table would I have to do an initialization for each table?

when I try to get some information from the groups table it returns that this table was not created

its my first aplication with too tables on flutter.

my code is below

```
import 'package:sqflite/sqflite.dart'; 
import 'package:path/path.dart';
/// COLUNAS DA TABELA CONTA
const String contastabela = 'contas';
const String idContas = 'idconta';
const String nomescontas = 'nomeconta';
const String despesascontas = 'despesaconta';
const String receitascontas = 'receitaconta';
const String datascontas = 'dataconta';
const String gruposcontas = 'grupoconta';
// COLUNAS DA TABELA GRUPOS
const String grupoTabelas = 'grupos';
const String idgrupos = 'idgrupo';
const String nomesgrupos = 'nomegrupo';



class HelperTransaction {

  static final HelperTransaction _instance = HelperTransaction.internal();

  factory HelperTransaction() => _instance; 

  HelperTransaction.internal();

  Database? _db; 

  Future<Database?> get db async {
    if(_db != null){
      return _db;
    }else{
      _db = await initDb();
      return _db;
    }
  }

  Future<Database> initDb() async{
    final databasesPath =  await getDatabasesPath();
    final path = join(databasesPath, "transactionnew2.db");

    return await openDatabase(path, version: 1, onCreate: (Database db, int newerVersion) async{
      await db.execute("CREATE TABLE $contastabela ($idContas INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, $nomescontas TEXT NOT NULL, $despesascontas DOUBLE (255) NOT NULL, $receitascontas DOUBLE (255) NOT NULL, $datascontas TEXT NOT NULL, $gruposcontas INT (255) REFERENCES $grupoTabelas (id) MATCH SIMPLE); CREATE TABLE $grupoTabelas ($idgrupos INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, $nomesgrupos TEXT NOT NULL,);"
      "INSERT INTO grupos (idgrupo, grupo) VALUES (1, 'Nenhum');"
      );
    });
  }
```

Comment: Correct.  To make two tables, you should create the group table first, then the other table referencing group.

Comment: Simply delete `,` after your last column name which is `$nomesgrupos TEXT NOT NULL,` it will be like this `$nomesgrupos TEXT NOT NULL`